# Why is the visited/not visited link color inverse than anywhere else?

Tags: support, design, hyperlinks

#### Academia.SE

[image: image description]

#### Stackoverflow.com

[image: image description]

#### Google.com

[image: image description]

#### SciFi.SE

[image: image description]

As you can see on the images, every site uses a rule that **visited link is darker and less apparent** than non visited one. I don't remember a site that would chose for inverse behavior.

I find this quite confusing. And after using this site on a while, I end up being confused on other "normal" sites as well - that makes this behavior actively harmful.

Comment: My guess is its due to our dark theme,  even though it's on a light background in your example